# Academic Snake Pit

Tags: grid-deduction

One day, you get lost in the corridors of your new school and accidentally wander into a pit full of venomous snakes. Unfortunately, the pit is deep and you have hurt your leg in the fall, so there is no climbing out. Fortunately, since you're in a school, all of the snakes are educated and would much rather force you to do a puzzle than eat you.

The snakes give you the following puzzle on a crumpled sheet of paper, under threat of death by poison should you fail to solve it. The front of the paper looks like this:

[image]

If you flip the paper over, the back looks like this:

[image]

Better not waste time! Although these snakes are academic, it certainly isn't above them to kill and eat a human.

**HINT:**

> The tape is there for a reason.

Comment: was the flip horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Horizontal. I had a feeling someone would ask that. :)

Comment: yeah, coz the paper itself doesn't look flipped.,.

Comment: **NOTE:** Minor tweak made to first image.

Comment: Meaning the axis of rotation is horizontal?

Comment: @DrXorile No, the axis of rotation is vertical. When you rotate the card, the top edges rotate in place, and the side edges switch places with each other.

Answer (score 4):

The puzzle is a

> [slitherlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink)

but played on a

> torus board, i.e. one where the edges wrap around.
>
>  From the snake on the back you can see that the left/right edges map exactly onto one another (regardless of how the rectangular paper is turned over, the snake shows short sides match). The top/bottom edges however don't map directly, but are slightly shifted. There are two ways they could connect, because there are two grid points directly on the top/bottom edges. After filling in the walls of the lower 3 square, the partial square below it has two walls. It therefore becomes clear that this square cannot be the 1 in the top row. The square below the bottom 3 must therefore be the 3 in the top row.
>
>  Once this mapping is known, it is just a matter of solving the slitherlink puzzle. It is straightforward, but slightly confusing due to the wrapping. Here is the solution, copied a few times to show the edge mapping.
>
>  [image]

Comment: Interesting, but not the solution I had in mind. I have added a hint to the question that gives a little bit more information.